# Can't run any "composer create-project" or "composer require" command

Tags: performance, repository, composer-php, packagist

I tried to clone some packages to my symfony projects, but it seems there are some issues with repository servers. 
My command stays there for ever and does nothing:

`$ php composer.phar require sonata-project/admin-bundle`

Does anyone know how to work around it?

Thanks,

Comment: There probably is something broken - try running `php composer.phar diag` and paste the results into your question, please.

Comment: I forgot to mention that yesterday ping symfony.com showed time out error.
Everything works fine today... 
Good to know about composer diag though... 

It came back with ok:
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking github.com oauth access: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
thank you for your help.